# iOS - detect when more than one finger is on the screen

Tags: iphone, ipad, touch, detection, gesture-recognition

I'm looking for the best way to detect more than one finger on the screen at time. I'm not detecting taps or pinching, just the fact that more than one touch is happening. There don't seem to be any gesture recognizers for that. What's the best way?

Comment: Is this for anywhere on the screen, or on a particular view?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the touchesBegan, touchesMoved, and touchesEnded methods, one parameter is event, which is a UIEvent object.  The number of fingers on the screen is [[event allTouches]count].

[EDITED because Josh Hinman pointed out that I had it wrong before -- my previous suggestion of using [touches count] on the touches parameter in those same methods will not work.]

Comment: I don't think that will reliably give you the total number of touches on the screen; only the number of touches that are being updated. In other words, if I have three fingers on the screen, and I move one finger while keeping the other two stationary, then touchesMoved: will be called with an NSSet of one touch (the one that I moved).

Answer (score 4):

Read up on the `-touchesBegan:withEvent:` method. It's the entry point into multi-touch event handling.

Here's a developer's lib link on multitouch events:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MultitouchEvents/MultitouchEvents.html

Comment: I tried this in the view controller, but it never gets called:    -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
 NSLog(@"num touches: %d", [touches count]);
}

Answer (score 1):

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

  NSLog(@"%lu",[[event allTouches] count]);
  }

Answer (score 0):

One/Multi touch is transparent to you - You just get notifications on where a touch started/moved/ended/tapped. If two touches occur at the same time, you will get notifications for both.

I don't know of any built-in function which determines whether or not the touch sequences you see consist of a pinch - But you can take a look at the "touches" sample code from Apple for inspiration.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Touches/

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a UITapGestureRecognizer class, and set the [numberOfTouchesRequired](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITapGestureRecognizer/numberOfTouchesRequired) property to 2.

Note that this will only work if [multipleTouchEnabled](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/multipleTouchEnabled) is set to YES on the view.